# Postgres pg_trgm Extension Creation Error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have installed Postgres 9.5 in an attempt to install GitLab. As part of the process the trigram extension (`pg_trgm`) needs to be created on the database. When I issue the create statement I get the following error:

> ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/pg_trgm.control": No such file or directory

Presumably there was a version of Postgres 9.1 on the server previously and the extension control file is currently found at `/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/pg_trgm.control`. How do I get the `psql` instance to see the extension in the 9.5 directory?

Comment: Have you checked if your postgres config(s) might still be pointing to the 9.1 directory? Did you also check what version of PG is in fact running currently?

Comment: The error was having some 9.1 and 9.3 packages still installed. I had tried removing the packages but apparently not gotten all of them. I don't know if this qualifies as an answer-worthy response.

Comment: This error can also occur if you're missing the `postgresql-contrib` package on ubuntu/debian.